# JayData "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, wcf-data-services, svc, jaydata

Have a Model where I want to be able to log the devicetypes of a connection by doing this:

```
var connections = DataLayer.context.ConnectionSet.filter(function(item) {
     return item.Id == id;
}, {id: 1});

connections.forEach(function(item) {
     console.log(item.Sender.Device.DeviceType);
});
```

`item.Sender.Device.DeviceType` results in this error:
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

This is my model:

```
 $data.Entity.extend('SubliminalData.Connection', {
    'Id': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true },
    'Sender': { 'type':'SubliminalData.DevicePort','required':true },
    'Receiver': { 'type':'SubliminalData.DevicePort','required':true }
  });

  $data.Entity.extend('SubliminalData.Device', {
    'Id': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true },
    'DeviceType': { 'type':'Edm.String','nullable':false,'required':true }
  });

  $data.Entity.extend('SubliminalData.Port', {
    'Id': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true }
  });

  $data.Entity.extend('SubliminalData.DevicePort', {
    'Id': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true },
    'Device': { 'type':'SubliminalData.Device','required':true },
    'Port': { 'type':'SubliminalData.Port','required':true }
  });
```

Why is this giving me a maximum call exception and how can I fix it? I couldn't find it.

--UPDATE--

I have been trying to get it work lately and I have changed my model so that I have backwards navigation properties. It makes more sense now, but now I have another problem.

New model:

```
$data.Entity.extend('SubliminalData.Connection', {
    'Id': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true },
    'Sender': { 'type':'SubliminalData.DevicePort','required':true,'inverseProperty':'SendingConnections' },
    'Receiver': { 'type':'SubliminalData.DevicePort','required':true,'inverseProperty':'ReceivingConnections' }
  });

  $data.Entity.extend('SubliminalData.Device', {
    'Id': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true },
    'DeviceType': { 'type':'Edm.String','nullable':false,'required':true },
    'DevicePorts': { 'type':'Array','elementType':'SubliminalData.DevicePort','inverseProperty':'Device' }
  });

  $data.Entity.extend('SubliminalData.Port', {
    'Id': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true },
    'PortType': { 'type':'Edm.String','nullable':false,'required':true },
    'DevicePorts': { 'type':'Array','elementType':'SubliminalData.DevicePort','inverseProperty':'Port' }
  });

  $data.Entity.extend('SubliminalData.DevicePort', {
    'Id': { 'key':true,'type':'Edm.Int32','nullable':false,'computed':true },
    'Device': { 'type':'SubliminalData.Device','required':true,'inverseProperty':'DevicePorts' },
    'Port': { 'type':'SubliminalData.Port','required':true,'inverseProperty':'DevicePorts' },
    'SendingConnections': { 'type':'Array','elementType':'SubliminalData.Connection','inverseProperty':'Sender' },
    'ReceivingConnections': { 'type':'Array','elementType':'SubliminalData.Connection','inverseProperty':'Receiver' }
  });

  $data.EntityContext.extend('DataLayer.SubliminalDataContainer', {
    'ConnectionSet': { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: SubliminalData.Connection },
    'DeviceSet': { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: SubliminalData.Device },
    'PortSet': { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: SubliminalData.Port },
    'DevicePortSet': { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: SubliminalData.DevicePort }
  });

  $data.generatedContexts = $data.generatedContexts || [];
  $data.generatedContexts.push(DataLayer.SubliminalDataContainer);

  /*Context Instance*/
  DataLayer.context = new DataLayer.SubliminalDataContainer( { name:'oData', oDataServiceHost: 'http://localhost:57703/WcfDataService1.svc' });
```

My new problem is this:

```
var connections = DataLayer.context.ConnectionSet.filter(function(item) {
        return item.Id == id;
    }, {id: 1});

connections.forEach(function(item) {
    l(item); //works great!
    l(item.Sender); //undefined :[

});
```

Why is my Sender undefined? I thought I understood JayData, but I'm to believe I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok, we think that you get this error from other part of your code,
most probably from a recursive function call.
Can you create a jsfiddle with your code so we can test it ?

Comment: sorry, we can not help with so little info, provide more

Comment: My problem has changed, maybe you can help with that? I've updated the description

Comment: You have to include it filter(..).include('Sender')